# C: using the system() command

Tags: c, error-handling, system

I'm writing a program that acts as a simple shell. Users call the program from the command line and are prompted to enter commands that are sent to the OS for completion. It should run until the user enters "done", at which point the program should break. I'm running into a problem with entering done - the program quits as it should, but prints

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
sh: -c: line 0: `done'
```

to the terminal before finishing execution. Here's the code I've written that applies:

```
char isDone[] = "done\n"; //fgets stores the new line character from the command line

do {
    printf(">>"); //print the prompt each time through the loop
    fgets(command, 50, stdin); //get a line from the terminal
    system(command);
} while (strcmp(command, isDone) != 0); //break the loop if the user types in done
```

I think the error has to do with the fact "done" is not a valid UNIX command, but I'm not sure how to deal with this error. I tried solving this problem with the following fix:

```
if(system(command) == -1){
    printf("The OS doesn't recognize this command");
}
else
    system(command);
```

But that didn't solve the problem or printing the errors to the screen, and created a second problem of printing the commands/errors twice - once in the if conditional block, and once in the else block. How can I solve this problem?

***EDIT***
This is a homework question the requires using a do-while. Is there a solution that uses a do-while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `do...while` construct executes its body *before* the loop condition is checked. So by the time the loop "realizes" that the user entered `done`, it has already tried to execute that input as a command inside the loop body.

The clearest way to fix this is to use `break`:

```
while (1)
{
    fgets(command, 50, stdin);
    if (!strcmp(command, isDone)) break;
    system(command);
}
```

The reason to structure it this way is that each iteration consists of both actions that should be done before the condition (reading in the user input) and actions that should be done after the condition (executing the command with `system()`). Because of this, neither a `do...while` or simple `while` will allow you to structure your code intuitively. The `break` keyword gives you a way to put the loop's termination condition in the middle of the loop body.

Comment: As this is for a homework assignment, we are required to use a do-while. Can you think of a solution that uses do-while? –

Comment: It is possible, but not cleanly or without code repetition. Because of what I said about having actions both before and after the termination condition, `do...while` is an extremely poor control flow construct for this purpose. I'd tell my professor that (I never was a very good or popular student).

Comment: Haha ok I'll let him know.

Answer (score 0):

The order of execution is:

```
fgets(command, 50, stdin); //get a line from the terminal
system(command);
strcmp(command, isDone) != 0
```

So the line "done" is read, sent to system (which tries to execute it as a shell command, printing an error) and only then it checks it.

You can try something like that:

```
for(;;){
    printf(">>"); //print the prompt each time through the loop
    fgets(command, 50, stdin); //get a line from the terminal
    if(!strcmp(command, isDone)) break; //break the loop
    system(command);
}
```

Edit: if you want to keep the do-while:

```
printf(">>"); //print the prompt each time through the loop
fgets(command, 50, stdin); //get a line from the terminal
do {
    system(command);
    printf(">>"); //print the prompt each time through the loop
    fgets(command, 50, stdin); //get a line from the terminal
} while (strcmp(command, isDone) != 0); //break the loop if the user types in done
```

But the `break` version is clearly more readable.

Comment: As this is for a homework assignment, we are required to use a do-while. Can you think of a solution that uses do-while?

Comment: @itscharlieb if you give a little thought to it, I think you could come up with a way to apply this concept into your own code, based on only the contents of what you pasted and pod answered with.

Comment: The break works, but it implies that the comparison of the do-while isn't of any use, which is why I'm hesitant to use that as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After the fgets(), do the system() call inside an if statement:

```
if ( strcmp( isDone, command) != 0 ) {
    system( command );
}
```